# 404 error htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect a 404 error to a custom php page, 404.php.

I'm using this code in my .htaccess file but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone point out what I might be doing wrong?

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /$1/$2.php 
RewriteRule ^s/([^/]*)$ /s.php?share=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: What is not working? it does not redirect or redirect but with error 404 message and you don't want that?

Comment: Try putting `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` on top of everything (as in on top of `Options -Multiviews`). It probably thinks that's it's part of your `RewriteCond` rule.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did that but it still does not work

Comment: @Prix it does not redirect. It displays apaches default not found page

Comment: @KwaasiDjin and do you have a `404.php` file on `/home/youraccount/public_html` folder?

Comment: @KwaasiDjin **Silly question ALERT** - Do you in fact have a page called `404.php`? If not, then that'll do it.

Comment: What URL are you using test this 404 condition?

Comment: Oops... seems like my question was already asked. *My bad*

Comment: @Prix the 404.php is in my root folder.

Comment: @KwaasiDjin remove the 4 lines above it and give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: What is your URL and what content you have in 404.php?

Answer (score 0):

Put ErrorDocument line on top of everything.

And: a server restart is needed afaik in order to re-read .htaccess and apply any changes in there (reload will not work).

Did you restart your server?